# OSGi+Websocket+Jetty = ClassNotFoundException: org....WebSocketServerFactory

Tags: websocket, jetty, osgi

I am trying to create a `WebSocket Server` in an OSGi environment:

```
public class MyServer {
    private Server server = null;

    public void startServer(String wsHost, int wsPort, String wsPath) throws Exception {
        server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setHost(wsHost);
        connector.setPort(wsPort);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.addServlet(MessagingServlet.class, "/"+wsPath);
        server.start();
    }

    public void stopServer() throws Exception {
        if (server != null)
            server.stop();
    }
}

public class MessagingServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.register(EventSocket.class);
    }
}

public class EventSocket extends WebSocketAdapter {
    private final CountDownLatch closureLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketConnect(Session sess) {
        super.onWebSocketConnect(sess);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
        super.onWebSocketText(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode, reason);
        closureLatch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
        super.onWebSocketError(cause);
    }
}
```

This code above works well outside an OSGi environment, however in OSGi it throws the exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory not found by org.eclipse.jetty.util`.

I found a website (http://eriklievaart.com/web/osgiwebsockets.html) that proposes a solution for this, but it does not work with the dependencies it shows there, the dependencies are somewhat old. Does anyone knows how to get this (potential solution) working with the approach I describe above?

**UPDATE:**

OSGi Felix version: 7.0.1, Jetty Version: 9.4.46

Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to specify which OSGi environment are you using. Or even which version of Jetty.

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek Question updated with environment versions.

Comment: From OSGi point of view, jetty-util bundle imports only `org.eclipse.jetty.util.*` Jetty packages. So no wonder that it can't find `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory` class. The point is what lead to such situation that this bundle wants to load `WebSocketServerFactory`?

Comment: BTW, I've just run all integration tests of Pax Web 8 using Jetty 9.4.46 and all run fine (including WebSocket integration tests).

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek But, were those tests from Jetty WebSocket or PAX WebSocket?

Comment: Pax Web itself doesn't have "own websockets" - there are tests showing javax.websocket API usage using Jetty, Tomcat and Undertow. See this test - https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/main/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-common/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/container/websockets/AbstractWebSocketIntegrationTest.java

Comment: Interesting. Do you have some sort of example or working demo with OSGi + Jetty + WebSocket + PAX?

Comment: This sample should work: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/main/samples/samples-war/war-websocket-jsr356 as shown in this test: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/main/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-common/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/container/websockets/AbstractWebSocketIntegrationTest.java